# How to stop NewRelic from running on my local machine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, newrelic

I am using the New Relic monitoring service with the .NET agent. It runs on the production server.

However, I also get statistics from my local machine when I am testing/developing the application. I used the *New Relic Server Monitor Configuration* tool to stop the service, and also disabled it with `services.msc`. But I still see my local machine in the "servers" section when I check my application on newrelic.com.

What should I do (either in my application or with my machine) to stop this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows Server Monitor is a different application from the .Net Agent.  You will need to disable the .Net Agent in order for your development system to stop sending data to your application.  If you don't want to have the .Net Agent run at all on your development system you can alter the newrelic.config file in %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\New Relic\.NET Agent to disable it by changing the following:

`<configuration xmlns="urn:newrelic-config" agentEnabled="true">`

to

`<configuration xmlns="urn:newrelic-config" agentEnabled="false">`

This has the advantage of being set globally, but if you want to turn it on and off per application you can add the following in the web application's web.config:

`<appSettings>
  <add key="NewRelic.AgentEnabled" value="false"/>
</appSettings>`

Answer (score 0):

I have multiple Azure service configurations (ServiceConfiguration.(Release/Local).cscfg. I simply removed the licensekey from the Local configuration. And uninstalled the two agents on my Windows machine (via Change or Remove a Program).

When I ran the project again locally, it didn't report, so all is good ;)